# Conda biopython environment

Tags: conda

I am trying to create a conda environment from a yaml file with a single entry. The solving environment process takes ages. Can you please tell me how to accelerate the solving process ?

environ.yaml

```
channels:
  - bioconda
dependencies:
  - biopython   >=1.70
```

```
conda env create -n biopython -f environ.yaml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [Bioconda has specific channel requirements](https://bioconda.github.io/user/install.html#set-up-channels) which should be followed. You may have Conda Forge already in your local channel configuration, but it is better practice to explicitly include it in the YAML.

Second, only specifying `biopython` leaves the actual Python version open, and can result in extensive solving. You should get improved solving by specifying Python up through the minor version.

Third, the Conda solver is notoriously slow, especially once the Conda Forge channel is in play. Many in the bioinformatics community have been adopting [Mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba#readme), which is a compiled (faster!) drop-in replacement. It's simple to install (`conda install -n base conda-forge::mamba`), then just use it like one would `conda`.<sup>**1**</sup>

Summing up, try something like:

**environ.yaml**

```yaml
name: biopython
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.9
  - biopython>=1.70
```

then

```
mamba env create -n biopython -f environ.yaml
```

---

<sub>**[1]** Note that `mamba` does not replace `conda activate`, which is a shell function. But commands part of the `conda` and `conda-env` entrypoints, like `install`, `create`, `remove`, etc., each have a `mamba` counterpart.</sub>